# Caculating probability using normal distribution. and t-distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have this sample:

```
x=c(92L, 9L, 38L, 43L, 74L, 16L, 75L, 55L, 39L, 77L, 76L, 52L, 
100L, 85L, 62L, 60L, 49L, 28L, 6L, 27L, 63L, 22L, 23L, 99L, 61L, 
25L, 19L, 48L, 91L, 57L, 97L, 84L, 31L, 87L, 1L, 21L, 30L, 41L, 
13L, 72L, 68L, 95L, 47L, 11L, 24L, 58L, 18L, 67L, 33L, 8L, 50L, 
4L, 40L, 12L, 73L, 78L, 86L, 69L, 44L, 83L, 94L, 65L, 37L, 70L, 
54L, 46L, 15L, 53L, 89L, 98L, 90L, 3L, 14L, 17L, 42L, 45L, 79L, 
20L, 32L, 34L, 64L, 88L, 81L, 96L, 59L, 71L, 56L, 26L, 51L, 29L, 
80L, 7L, 36L, 93L, 82L, 35L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 66L)
```

I want to calculate this probability: `P(x) > Mean(x) + 3` assuming that data have normal distribution.

So I do this: `mean(x) = 50.5 ; sd(x)=29.01`

I generate the density distribution and calculate my probability, which now is:

```
P(x) > 53.5

pnorm(53.5, mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), lower.tail=FALSE)
```

If I want calculating using Standard Distribution:

```
P(x)>(53.5) = P(z=(x-mean(x)/sd(x))) > ((53.5 - 50.5)/29.01) = P(z)>(3/29.01)

pnorm(3/29.01149, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

But when I want to use the T-Student Distribution, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more legitimate to use `t` distribution here, as standard error is estimated from data.

```
pt(3 / sd(x), df = length(x) - 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.4589245
```

We have `length(x)` number of data, but also estimate 1 parameter (standard error), so the degree of freedom for t-distribution is `length(x) - 1`.

There is not much difference compared with using normal distribution, though, given that `length(x)` is 100 (which is large enough):

```
pnorm(3 / sd(x), lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.4588199
```

Comment: Should not we have (X-mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n)) ~ N(0,1) by CLT for normal distribution and (X-mu)/(s/sqrt(n)) ~ t(df=n-1) for sample size n? Here X=53.3, but where is population parameters mu & sigma for Normal distribution although we have s=sd(x) for t distribution. Where are we using the sample size to define our test-statistic?

Comment: so we are standardizing (computing z-score) without using sample size at all, without computing the standard error (by not accounting for the sample size), then which theory are we using to conclude that the test statistic also convergences in distribution to a standard normal distribution (if not CLT)? because later we are using the CDF for standard normal to compute the probabilities.